# I want to let user create Folder on Google Drive without any further signing

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

My purpose is to provide service on my server based on Google Drive platform. The most importantly user don't need to sign in or have google account to access this service.

As developer I want to authorize my web site URL and the Google Drive that will be mine.

I went through various solution but don't get actual one.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic and follow the steps there

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#serviceaccounts) about service accounts which enables your web application to interact with google servers. The docs says:

> A service account's credentials include a generated email address that is unique and at least one public/private key pair. If domain-wide delegation is enabled, then a client ID is also part of the service account's credentials.